# Hide Scroll but not Scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I managed to customize the scrollbar area with pure css but haven't been able to figure out how to make it so that the scroll area (white) is hidden.  I only want the bar itself, is this possible?

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/2qh2yy2o/

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.scrollbar-inner').scrollbar();
      jQuery('html').scrollbar();
});
```

```css
body{
  height:1000px;
  background:blue;
}
.scrollbar-inner{
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
  overflow:auto;
}
.content{
  height:1000px;
  width:100%;
}/*************** SCROLLBAR BASE CSS ***************/
/* For the "inset" look only */
html {
    overflow: auto;
}


/* Let's get this party started */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
    background:transparent;
}
 
/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(255,255,0,0.3); 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
 
/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #545454; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
 background: transparent; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.scrollbar/0.2.10/jquery.scrollbar.min.js
"></script>

<div class="scrollbar-inner"><div class="content"></div></div>
```

Comment: are you aware it don't works on firefox?

Comment: This isn't necessarily an answer, but just a warning: scrollbar styling is notoriously difficult, and impossible in a couple of browsers. You can do it in webkit browsers by setting a property, but any nonwebkit browser won't work. And even if you do set that property, I've done it before and it's buggy.

Comment: just twondering if you hide the scroll bar (check the forum - there are posts on how to hide the scroll bar with overflow: hidden) amd then create a custom scroll indicator element that moves down the page using the amount of scroll occurring with the  window.scroll property? Styling / modifying the actual scroll bar is way difficult, but this lets you create your own.